# Changing the placement and size of the graphs with matplib python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, matplotlib

How could I separate each graph with a certain distance away from one another and increase the size of the graph separately. As seen on the picture example below You could see that the title names are very close to each other and I would like to modify the graphs so that they are far apart from each other enough. I would also like to increase the size of each graph and give them different orientations.

```
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
gs = fig.add_gridspec(6, 3)

#Plotting the compounding amount 
a1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:3, 0]) #subplot (row, column)
a1.set_title('Compounding Amount')
a1.plot(bar_positions_x_list,Amount_list)

#plotting the non compounding amount
c1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[3:6,0])
c1.set_title('Non-Compounding Amount')
c1.plot(bar_positions_x_list, Non_compounding_list)

#plotting the short compounding amount 
a2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:3, 1])
a2.set_title('Short Compounding')
a2.plot(x_short, S_Amount_list)

#plotting the long compounding amount
a3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[3:6, 1])
a3.set_title('Long Compounding')
a3.plot(x_long,L_Amount_list)


c2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2:4, 2])
c2.set_title('Short Non-Compounding')
c2.plot(x_short,S_Non_compounding_list)

c3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[4:6, 2])
c3.set_title('Long Non-Compounding')
c3.plot(x_long,L_Non_compounding_list)

plt.show()
```

Graphs:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase the size of the entire figure (thereby also increasing the sizes of the individual subplots) [by providing a `figsize` argument to `plt.figure`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html) with two values (width and height of the figure in inches). By default, this is set to `[6.4, 4.8]`. For example, to double both the width and the height:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[12.8, 9.6], constrained_layout=True)
```

As the font size is not increased when changing the `figsize`, this will most likely move your subplot titles far enough apart. However, if you want to increase the distance even more, you can use [the `wspace` and `hspace` arguments of the `GridSpec` constructor](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html) to configure spacing between subplots. Both values are floats between `0` and `1`, and are "the amount of width/height reserved for space between subplots, expressed as a fraction of the average axis width/height" (cited from the documentation). You will most likely have to tweak these values to get a desired result, but you can use them as follows:

```
gs = fig.add_gridspec(6, 3, wspace=0.1, hspace=0.1)
```

However, the `constrained_layout` setting causes matplotlib to ignore the `wspace` and `hspace` values, so you would have to set this to `False`.